# Creating triangle shape xml without wasting space android

Tags: android, shapes

The solutions I have found over internet cuts the rectangle but I am having like half of it without nothing and wasting space.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="-40%"
            android:pivotY="87%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent" android:width="10dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/black" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This code creates a triangle, but I have a lot of space wasted, look at the image:

[image: Triangle with given code]

I want to create a triangle that "fills" the image view. Something like this:

[image]

Not necessarily has to be equilateral. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it is okay for you to create the shape in `java` , you can do it by extending the `Drawable` class in Android. See [this](https://github.com/telerik/Android-samples/blob/master/Store-Demo/Examples/java/com/telerik/examples/primitives/drawables/Triangle.java)